# Adding and removing classes produces race condition when used within setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have 2 objects on one, need to make both of them getting classes:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var delayMillis = 200; 
    $('#overtop').hover(function(){ $('#honemove').addClass('hover');}, function () { setTimeout(function() { $('#honemove').removeClass('hover'); }, delayMillis); });
    $('#overtop').hover(function(){ setTimeout(function() { $('#htwomove').addClass('hover'); }, delayMillis); }, function () { $('#htwomove').removeClass('hover'); });
});
</script>

<div id="overtop" class="overlay"></div>
<h1 id="honemove" class="h1a"><span>TITLE OF THE TITLE</span></h1>
<h2 id="htwomove"><span>INFO BELLOW TITLE</span></h2>
```

It works currently, but it glitches if u do a lot of mouse hovers, the CSS part is fine, I guess it doesn't like having two separate scripts on one action.

Comment: How is this CSS related?

Comment: I am sorry, it adds css, to the divs, but I wrongly did put the tag one, I apologize.

Comment: Okay, no worries @T.Lowly - I have tried replicating your code but it doesn't appear to be working. Can you put it in a codepen with your CSS too?

Comment: main thing i can see is that if you hover twice, before the first timeout to remove the css has fired you will add the css then remove early as the first timeout fires making it seem like it did not wait the desired time.

Comment: @Quince Thats excacly what is happening, thanks for pointing it out. would it be possible to make a timer so the action would finish in any way?

Comment: the main thing i would say then is if you want to clear/start fresh on a second hover keep a reference to the timeout then clear it if it exists before setting a new timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout) to prevent any sort of race condition from occurring:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $overtop = $('#overtop')
  var $honemove = $('#honemove')
  var $htwomove = $('#htwomove')
  
  var delay = 200
  var token
  
  $overtop.hover(function() {
    clearTimeout(token)
    $honemove.addClass('hover')
    token = setTimeout(function() {
      $htwomove.addClass('hover')
    }, delay)
  }, function() {
    clearTimeout(token)
    $htwomove.removeClass('hover')
    token = setTimeout(function() {
      $honemove.removeClass('hover')
    }, delay)
  })
});
```

```css
.hover {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="overtop" class="overlay">Overlay</div>
<h1 id="honemove" class="h1a"><span>TITLE OF THE TITLE</span></h1>
<h2 id="htwomove"><span>INFO BELLOW TITLE</span></h2>
```